# Command to print the CPU/RAM usage during the duration of another command/script

Tags: command, cpu, ram

I am doing some performance testing on a tool I wrote consisting of an elaborate set of python scripts, yml files, etc. I have been using the `time` command before running my primary python script so I can get an output of the time it took to run the tool. I am wondering if there is a similar command to this, but would be able to give me information on CPU/RAM usages. Potentially the average of each while the script was running.

Let me know if this can't be easily done and I need to ask the question somewhere else because it requires adding code to the python script.